# Mac display failure when disconnecting form Thunderbolt

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt-display

I have a MacBook Pro (the older one with a cd-rom), running OSX 10.9.1 and sometimes my Mac will sleep and never wake up. Usually this happens when I "sleep" the mac, unplug it from the Thunderbolt, then try to wake the Mac up at my other office with a different Thunderbolt. The screen will never come back. Tried safe restart, multiple combinations of plugged/unplugged to Thunderbolt and/or Power Supply, and open/shutting the screen.

It takes a very long time and many attempts to bring the screen back, usually by trying a 3rd Thunderbolt screen. There is clearly some sort of display issue, but the parameters are known. Any ideas what the precise problem is and how to fix it?

Comment: Exactly what is connected via Thunderbolt at the two offices?

Comment: Hi there, to maybe tell you what is going on we need your Console report at the time stamp of the event (sleep+unplug), gives us some 20 lines or so, not the whole 7 pages :)